# Need to access different LDAP services using .NET

Tags: php, .net, frameworks, ldap, openldap

I need to access different LDAP services using .NET. The client might have MS AD structure or UNIX based LDAP servers and I have to build a common framework to be able to access both.

Zend provide such tools but they are on PHP.

Can any one help me find a paid/free tool which works with .NET, enabling us to achieve the above?

Cheers,
Anshuman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/n Software has the IP*Works! toolkit which has an LDAP component in it. You can find a trial version for the .Net edition of the IP*Works! toolkit at http://www.nsoftware.com/download/download.aspx?part=IPN9-A&prod=demo&type=exe.

Note that this is paid software.